# Default :test in MEMBER doesn't find '(A B) in '((A B))

Tags: common-lisp

What is the default test that [**member**](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/f_mem_m.htm#member) uses when searching a list, and why does this fail to find a list? I am using GNU CLISP 2.49.

```
>(setq X '(A B))
>(member X '((A B)))
NIL
>(member X (list X))
((A B))
>(equal (list X) '((A B)))
T
>(member X '((A B)) :test #'equal)
((A B))
```

Comment: It defaults to `:TEST #'EQL`, see [Satisfying a Two-Argument Test](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/17_ba.htm).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

it's not immediately obvious where to find the answer to this.  Browsing the HyperSpec at a higher level can be very helpful.  While it can be tedious the first couple of times, you'll get a lot out of the documentation, and it's usually "reusable"—the answers to lots of similar questions are in the same place.

In this case, as [jkiiski mentioned in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38703878/clisp-default-member-test-cannot-match-a-list-within-another-list#comment64785745_38703878), the answer is in 
[17.2.1 Satisfying a Two-Argument Test](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/17_ba.htm), which states:

> If neither a :test nor a :test-not argument is supplied, it is as if a :test argument of #'eql was supplied.

(**Note:** it's worth noting exactly what this does and doesn't say.  This *doesn't* say that the default value of the test argument is **#'eql**, and it doesn't say that if the value of the **test** or **test-not** argument is **nil**, then **#'eql** is used.  I point this out not so much for **test**, but the related **key** argument can often be **nil** *or* not provided, in which case it is as though **#'identity** is used.)

It also lists which functions this applies to, describes how the arguments for the test (or test-not) function are computed (based on the key argument), and some other useful tidbits of information.

While you're in this section, it's also worth browsing "up" to the parent section, [17.2 Rules about Test Functions](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/17_b.htm), and to the grandparent section, [17. Sequences](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/17_.htm), and having a look through those.