# Common Lisp: where is default test for MEMBER, FIND, and POSITION specified?

Tags: common-lisp

I'm looking at the Common Lisp HyperSpec and I don't see where the default test for [MEMBER](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/f_mem_m.htm), [FIND](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/f_find_.htm), and [POSITION](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/f_pos_p.htm) is specified. Am I overlooking something obvious?

Word on the street is that EQL is the default test, but I would feel more comfortable knowing that's in the spec somewhere.

Comment: Not an exact duplicate based on title, but [Default :test in MEMBER doesn't find '(A B) in '((A B))](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38703878/1281433) asks **"What is the default test that member uses when searching a list, and why does this fail to find a list?"** and the answer points to the same reference.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This can be found here in the HyperSpec: [17.2.1 Satisfying a Two-Argument Test](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/17_ba.htm). A list of sequence functions, including `member`, `find`, and `position`, is given. These functions take a two-argument `:test` or `:test-not` argument.

> If neither a `:test` nor a `:test-not` argument is supplied, it is as if a `:test` argument of `#'eql` was supplied.